# "eclipse.exe has stopped working" while adding new workspace or switching workspace

Tags: eclipse, windows, crash, startup, workspace

From last few days i am getting one issue in eclipse while **adding new workspace or sometimes switching between workspaces**.

Please check this image.

[image]

i tried by changing heap size in **eclipse.ini** and also did some other stuff to fix this issue. i also searched on Google but not getting perfect solution.

I got some solutions while searching but its quite different because i am getting this issue **while adding new workspace**.

Way i am getting this issue.
1. Open Eclipse
2. Browser New workspace folder
3. Eclipse open
4. Just after 2 3 seconds it will crash with the message displaying in image.

Please help me to rectify this issue. Thankx in Advance.